# Chromium executable isn't found in Docker environment

Tags: node.js, docker, azure-functions, playwright

I'm trying to run a docker image in kubernetes. In this image I want Playwright to be able to run, but for some reason the program can't find the executable. I'm getting this error:

```
Executable doesn't exist at /home/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-1041/chrome-linux/chrome
```

I'm running in an Azure Function. This is my Dockerfile:

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node16-appservice
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-focal

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node16

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libdrm-dev libxkbcommon-dev libgbm-dev libasound-dev libatspi2.0-0 libxshmfence-dev

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Does anyone know?

Comment: The multiple `FROM` lines set up a multi-stage build, but you're not actually using the earlier stage at all.  Your image is based on the Azure Node image and not Playwright at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COPY` instead of `FROM`

Something like below

```
# To enable ssh & remote debugging on app service change the base image to the one below
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node16-appservice
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-focal

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/node:4-node16

COPY --from=mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.28.0-focal /home/.cache/ms-playwright /home/.cache/ms-playwright

ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

COPY . /home/site/wwwroot

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libdrm-dev libxkbcommon-dev libgbm-dev libasound-dev libatspi2.0-0 libxshmfence-dev

RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && \
    npm install && \
    npm run build
```

Using `COPY --from` you can copy all of the required files